# How does dynamic content replacement affect PPC quality score?

Tags: javascript, google-ads, jquery, ppc

I'm looking to write a script that dynamically replaces elements of my page with content related to the keyword that resulted in a PPC click. For example, visiting the landing page after searching on "purple widgets" would replace the hero image with an image of a purple widget, and the h1 with copy related to purple widgets.

How does this affect quality score? Are there any downsides of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The effect shouldn't be grave. AdWords QS is mainly related to CTR%, i.e. everything that happens before someone visits the site.

Onsite optimization primarily improves your Conversion rates, not your QS. Still, there could be a positive effect, since Google also checks for what they call [Quality of the landing page](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2454010?hl=en), which is related to unique content, page load time, ease of navigation, etc.

Hence, if it helps your site it will improve QS, but this effect will be minimal. I don't see any downsides as long as this doesn't slow down your site too much.